# ICommand _canExecute problem

Tags: wpf, delegates, icommand

I have the following code and it won't compile because the compiler cannot determine the return type of my CanExecute method.  Can someone help me as to what is wrong?

```
class ViewCommand : ICommand
    {
        #region ICommand Members

        public delegate Predicate<object> _canExecute(object param);
        private ICommand _Execute;

        _canExecute exe;

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return exe == null ? true : exe(parameter); // <-- Error no implicit conversion between Predicate<object> and bool
        }

... // more code
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ICommand interface declares `CanExecute` as a function that takes a parameter and returns a bool.

Your `_canExecute` takes a parameter and returns a `Predicate<object>`

The way to invoke that would be to pass the parameter to the return value of `exe`

```
exe(parameter)(parameter);
```

I doubt that was your intention though.

I think you want to declare `exe` as a Predicate, and skip the delegate declaration.

```
private Predicate<object> exe;
```

This is what I think you want to look like:

```
class ViewCommand : ICommand
    {
        #region ICommand Members

        private ICommand _Execute;

        Predicate<object> exe;

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return exe == null ? true : exe(parameter); // <-- Error no implicit conversion between Predicate<object> and bool
        }

... // more code
}
```

Comment: Now, I did your last, but it still not happy with the return types... what could be wrong?

Comment: what is the definition of the predicate you are assigning to _canExecute?

Comment: private Predicate<object> _canExecute(object param);

Comment: found the problem! The (object param) bit! The predicate itself already specifies the param type, so didn't need to do it again.

Comment: @Tony, you don't need to define a delegate for that, it already exists and it is Predicate<Object>. It doesn't make sense to return a predicate anyway, you need to return a bool